# Download a CSV file in react js

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to make a downloadable link using React JS. But when I click the link it popups a message as "couldn't download - no file". Here I attach my code. Please help me to solve this problem.

```
 function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
     <a href="/src/annual-enterprise-survey-2020-financial-year-provisional-csv.csv" target="_blank" download="annual-enterprise-survey-2020-financial-year-provisional-csv.csv"> Sample refund file </a>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: make sure your file path was correct `/src/annual-enterprise-survey-2020-financial-year-provisional-csv.csv`

Comment: As mentioned above, check the URL is correct. One easy way to do this is remove the download property and see where the link takes you.

Comment: yes it's correct

Comment: I removed the download property and click the link. Then it just refreshes the page.